# While debugging with an input from the keyboard, I want to able to skip the execution of a few lines of code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging, image-processing, user-input

Currently I have this excerpt of code I am trying to debug:

```
if (white_flag == 1)
    keyboard;
    imshow(rl_img);
    N = N+1; 
    times(times_index,1) = index; 
    while(white_flag == 1)
        imshow(rl_img);
        index = index+1; 

        %%% If statement for when the loop has run out
        if (index >= frames)
            break
        end

        %%% Initial Image Pre-Processing
        rl_img = ones(mod_height,width);
        pre_rl_img = medfilt2(vreader.read(index));
        for i = 1:mod_height
            for j = 1:width
                rl_img(i,j) = pre_rl_img(i,j); 
            end
        end

        white_flag = detect_white( rl_img, white_flag );
    end
    times(times_index,2) = index;
    times_index = times_index+1; 
else 
    index = index+ 1;
end
```

Now, as you can see, the debug keyboard input call `keybaord` is on the second line. While this allows me to efficiently see each step of the execution of my program, I do not understand how to skip over the part below:

```
        for i = 1:mod_height
            for j = 1:width
                rl_img(i,j) = pre_rl_img(i,j); 
            end
        end
```

This is a rather sizable picture(`rl_img`), so waiting for keyboard input while I scrawl through the code manually wastes a lot of time. Can someone please tell me how to skip the user input execution of these lines of code while I debug the program?

Please do not hesitate to ask me any questions that can clarify this problem. Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite straightforward:

1. you set a breakpoint *after* the lengthy loop,
2. when you decide to run automatically all the rest of the loop up to the breakpoint you just set, press [F5] (Continue).

This assumes that you debug your code in the normal MATLAB IDE.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Please note that the breakpoints you've set are removed from all the files once you performed a `clear all` call. This just in case you'll wonder "where my breakpoints went?" -- as it happened to me the first times... :-)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't want to step through each loop iteration.

You can either follow [CST-Link's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35085058/3871918) or you can avoid creating additional breakpoints by placing your cursor somewhere after the loop

[image]

and clicking 
[image] on the editor's debug panel.